# Having Problems skinning a DotNetNuke Menu

Tags: css, dotnetnuke

Is there a class that overwrites the .MainMenu_MenuItem class for the Main Menu? I try to change the font-size and color of the Topmost parent of the Main Menu(includes Admin,Host links) and they won't change.

I can change the background color.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Someone else seems to have had this problem before.](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/109/threadid/17879/scope/posts/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Firefox plugin called firefly will help a lot in figuring out what style is defined on a given element. Try it out!

Comment: You don't mean 'firebug' by any chance? Um...'firefly' in FF is a browser-based file manager according to the get add-ons tool...